# change the boot logo for 18.04 LTS

Tags: boot, logo

**how to change the boot logo(with commands) for 18.04 LTS**

Comment: while the OS is loading.. the purple background with ubuntu logo.. you mean this? its part of plymouth.. google `plymouth` you will get idea..

Answer (score 2):

by default, the boot logo for Ubuntu 18.04 uses `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.png` from the script `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script`

some of the content of this script is

```
    bits_per_pixel = Window.GetBitsPerPixel ();
if (bits_per_pixel == 4) {
    logo_filename = "ubuntu-logo16.png";
    progress_dot_off_filename = "progress-dot-off16.png";
    progress_dot_on_filename = "progress-dot-on16.png";
    password_field_filename = "password-field16.png";
    question_field_filename = "password-field16.png";
} else {
    logo_filename = "ubuntu-logo.png";
    progress_dot_off_filename = "progress-dot-off.png";
    progress_dot_on_filename = "progress-dot-on.png";
    password_field_filename = "password-field.png";
    question_field_filename = "password-field.png";
```

[image]

[image]

to change the boot logo by understanding above content of the script..
we need to replace `ubuntu-logo16.png` & `ubuntu-logo.png` files with our custome ones with same names..

you can easily do this with command line..

Example Command Line when my Custom Image is in `~/Downloads` with `boot.png` name

```
cd /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo
sudo mv ubuntu-logo.png ubuntu-logo.png.bak
sudo mv ubuntu-logo16.png ubuntu-logo16.png.bak
cd ~/Downloads
sudo cp boot.png /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.png
sudo cp boot.png /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo16.png
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Recommendations for custom boot logo image:
image format: .png
image size: around 217px in width

Comment: Thank you very much .. it works like magic with ubuntu 18.04lts