# How to change the background of the default Ubuntu splash screen in 19.04?

Tags: boot, gnome, themes, plymouth

The default Ubuntu Logo plymouth theme has the description "A theme that features a blank background with a logo." Instead of that "blank background" I want to have my own customised image as the background to the same logo with the four dots.
I know about the option of installing other plymouth themes, but I specifically want only to change the purple background of the default theme to an image.
I am using Ubuntu 19.04 Disco Dingo.
Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Open the file with below command

`sudo -H gedit /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script`

look for the content at line no. 192 (Please note that I have already changed line no. 192)

```
logo.image = Image (logo.jpg);
logo.sprite = Sprite ();
logo.sprite.SetImage (logo.image);
logo.width = logo.image.GetWidth ();
logo.height = logo.image.GetHeight ();
logo.x = Window.GetX () + Window.GetWidth () / 2 - logo.width  / 2;
logo.y = Window.GetY () + Window.GetHeight () / 2 - logo.height;
logo.z = 1000;
logo.sprite.SetX (logo.x);
logo.sprite.SetY (logo.y);
logo.sprite.SetZ (logo.z);
logo.sprite.SetOpacity (1);
```

at line no. 192 logo.jpg is the Image of my interest and its location must be `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/` as described in this file `/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth`

```
[Plymouth Theme]
Name=Ubuntu Logo
Description=A theme that features a blank background with a logo.
ModuleName=script

[script]
ImageDir=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo
ScriptFile=/usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.script
```

[image]

After saving the file, run `sudo update-initramfs -u` and the changes will be effective after a reboot.

Comment: Did not work. Line 192 of the original script is
`logo.image = Image(logo_filename)`
where logo_filename is a variable pointing to the Ubuntu logo file. Replacing this will replace the logo with a wallpaper screen. Not what I am looking for. 
The replacing did not work either for me. Only a blank purple (default) screen showed up at boot time.

Comment: Hi.. I Checked it in Ubuntu 19.04 and then posted. 0k..by your question it is understood like so. Can you edit your question to explain clearly what you are looking for. Thank You..

Comment: are you looking for this https://askubuntu.com/a/1122681/739431??

Comment: did you run `sudo update-initiramfs -u` after saving the file?

Comment: OK, if I Understood your question correctly.. you need to work out with images to achieve what you want.. I guess you need ubuntu text and circle with friends logo from `ubuntu-logo16.png` and then make your own changes and follow this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122675/change-the-boot-logo-for-18-04-lts/1122681#1122681