# can I use a custom boot logo?

Tags: boot, 20.04, bootloader

Can I use **MY Logo instead of ubuntu logo **.My logo is in png format ...

or Can I mka emy own boot splash?

> if yes then how can I do that and make my own boot splash

Thanks In advance

Keval Shah

Comment: Boot logo?  Do you mean using your own image as a `plymouth` logo? or as a `grub` background?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [change the boot logo for 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122675/change-the-boot-logo-for-18-04-lts)

Comment: Yes Thankyou all for answering my question is right answer

Comment: but can I use this steps in ubuntu 20.04

Comment: You weren't specific as to which 'steps' you meant; but the `plymouth` and `grub` haven't changed much over decade+

Comment: yeah I Checked the plymouth it's same but only the positions of the files have been changed and no big problem and thankyou for helping me out .